# Using a boolean in Thymeleaf th:action

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I send a boolean using the above?  For example the below fails

```
th:action="@{/list(foo=${true})}"
```

Comment: How does it fail - what is the error?

Comment: To use `${true}` you need to provide a variable named `true` in your Thymeleaf model. Something like `model.put("true", Boolean.TRUE);`. That will work. Or, hard-code the value using `"@{/list(foo='true')}"` in your template. Or, are you hitting some different issue?